# setImage always picks up 1x image

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I am trying to add a image to the `leftView` of a `UITextField`. I did this to add the image:

```
self.tfEmailId.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
UIImageView *imgSearch=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 25, self.tfEmailId.frame.size.height-5)];
[imgSearch setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Emailid@1x"]];
self.tfEmailId.leftView = imgSearch;
self.tfEmailId.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

Now the issue is when i run this in simulator (iPhone 6 Plus), the image appears very blurry, which means it is using the 1x one instead of 3x. How do i solve this. Also this does not happen in IB, i have other image views and when i assign them an image through IB and run in iPhone 6, it will automatically pick up 3x for me. Please explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the suffix for image. It will automatically pick image as per the device resolution. You have to put 3 images in image asset for Emailid.

Just remove `@1x` suffix from `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Emailid@1x"]` and try.